# Android/Cordova/Gradle:Keystore has been tampered with or password was incorrect

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, android-keystore

I want to make a Jenkins server build my Cordova based (Android) application. For that, I intend to use Gradle (because the project from Cordova has all necessary files). I released the application several times from `IntelliJ -> Export signed APK`, but I can't get the gradle'd version to be correctly signed with my keystore.

Here's what I configured:

## Keystore

Generated via `keytool`, already used to publish my application via Google Play Store. I thought Gradle might have a problem with special characters in the keystore and/or key password, so I used

`keytool -storepasswd -keystore mykeystore.keystore`

and

`keytool -keypasswd -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.keystore`

to change them. I'm 100% certain that my passwords are correct in my Gradle configuration files.

## Cordovas build.gradle

This file is pre-generated for the project, I didn't change much. I left the following lines untouched:

```
if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
            keyAlias = ""
            keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
            storeFile = null
            storePassword = "__unset"
        }
    }
    (snip)
}
```

To fulfill the `cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile` condition, I created a file `release-signing.properties` in the projects android directory (see http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-gradle-properties ).

```
storeFile=keystore/mykeystore.keystore
storePassword="my_password"
keyAlias="myalias"
keyPassword="my_password"
```

---

Now, when I run `./gradlew signingReport --info`, I get the following output:

```
Selected primary task 'signingReport' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':signingReport', task ':CordovaLib:signingReport']
:signingReport (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:signingReport
Executing task ':signingReport' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: (snip)
SHA1: (snip)
Valid until: Mittwoch, 3. Dezember 2042
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: release
Store: /Users/myusername/Documents/MyApplication/project/platforms/android/keystore/mykeystore.keystore
Alias: "myalias"
Error: Failed to read key "myalias" from store "/Users/myusername/Documents/MyApplication/project/platforms/android/keystore/mykeystore.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
----------
Variant: release
Config: release
Store: /Users/myusername/Documents/MyApplication/project/platforms/android/keystore/mykeystore.keystore
Alias: "myalias"
Error: Failed to read key "myalias" from store "/Users/myusername/Documents/MyApplication/project/platforms/android/keystore/mykeystore.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
----------
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: (snip)
SHA1: (snip)
Valid until: Mittwoch, 3. Dezember 2042
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: (snip)
SHA1: (snip)
Valid until: Mittwoch, 3. Dezember 2042
----------
:signingReport (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.292 secs.
:CordovaLib:signingReport (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:CordovaLib:signingReport
Executing task ':CordovaLib:signingReport' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: (snip)
SHA1: (snip)
Valid until: Mittwoch, 3. Dezember 2042
----------
Variant: release
Config: none
----------
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: (snip)
SHA1: (snip)
Valid until: Mittwoch, 3. Dezember 2042
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: (snip)
SHA1: (snip)
Valid until: Mittwoch, 3. Dezember 2042
----------
:CordovaLib:signingReport (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.008 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 23.152 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Runing a `./gradlew build` results in this error message:

> :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>
> :validateReleaseSigning
>
> :packageRelease FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.
>     Failed to read key "myalias" from store "/Users/myusername/Documents
>     /MyApplication/project/platforms/android/keystore
>     /mykeystore.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Any ideas on how to resolve that error?

Comment: In my experience, special characters can indeed be problematic - see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309975/android-release-keystore-issue-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-inc#comment70534955_19044478).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find the reason for Gradle being so stubborn, I removed the file `release-signing.properties` to let Gradle build the *unsigned* APK and used the following commands to sign the file in a shell script:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore mykeystore.keystore
               myapplication.apk mykeyalias -storepass mypassword

/path/to/somewhere/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.3/zipalign -v 4
               myapplication.apk myapplication-signed.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle signing process has problems in escaping possible backslashes in your store password or key password. I suspect that what happened to you is something similar.